# MYSQL max(timestamp) returns different results than max(id)

Tags: mysql

I am creating a query for a log system. The table contains 100,000 rows or so and I would like to remove duplicates for the the following columns and only return the latest entry.

Columns to avoid duplicates,

- user
- ip
- time_accessed
- mainlocation
- secondlocation
- thirdlocation
- did_user_have_access

The purpose of this is to see which portions of the site a user has visited. We do not need to know that they have visited a particular pages 100 times, we only need to know that they visited it once.

The table has the following columns,

- id
- user
- ip
- time_accessed
- mainlocation
- secondlocation
- thirdlocation
- task
- did_user_have_access

**My question is, why do the following queries return such drastic results? The MAX('id') query returns 450 results and the MAX(`time_accessed`) returns 835. Shouldn't they return the same ammount?**

```
SELECT DISTINCT mainlocation, secondlocation, thirdlocation, ip, user, did_user_have_access, time_accessed

FROM `log_table`

WHERE `id` IN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id

          FROM `log_table`

          GROUP BY `mainlocation`, `secondlocation`, `thirdlocation`, `ip`, `user`, `did_user_have_access`) 

ORDER BY `log_table`.`time_accessed` DESC;



SELECT DISTINCT mainlocation, secondlocation, thirdlocation, ip, user, did_user_have_access, time_accessed

FROM `log_table`

WHERE `time_accessed` IN (SELECT MAX(`time_accessed`) AS time_accessed

          FROM `log_table`

          GROUP BY `mainlocation`, `secondlocation`, `thirdlocation`, `ip`, `user`, `did_user_have_access`) 

ORDER BY `log_table`.`time_accessed` DESC;
```

Comment: Why would they? Depending on how the time_accessed column is populated, it's possible that there could be two records with the same values.

Comment: Thank you for your response! None of the returned rows contain the exact combination of columns with the same timestamp. Since I am using the distinct for all the available columns, shouldn't a particular combination of columns only be returned once if you use max(time_accessed). I apologize if im not explaining this properly but I am under the impression that if there are 100 rows with the same values for columns a,b,c, and d but different timestamps, MYSQL should only return the one with the highest timestamp.

Comment: Your conditions (where statement) are different. Before the distinct or a group by, the rows to consider are selected. In most cases, this will result in different final results.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how do you populate both fields you're applying MAX() to - it could hardly be answered, only guessed, perhaps.

Although... does this matter? If you get a proper result - does it?

Then, you don't have to split it into two queries - as you're grouping results exactly by the fields you expect to be de-duped, you guaranteed to have **unique combinations** with MAX() in the main query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mainlocation, secondlocation, thirdlocation, 
     ip, user, did_user_have_access, 
     MAX(`time_accessed`) AS last_accessed
FROM log_table
GROUP BY mainlocation, secondlocation, thirdlocation, 
         ip, user, did_user_have_access
```

In other words, each six-tuple would be unique with each `last_accesed`